# how do i scrape data from a website using selenium?

Tags: python

Hello  I am trying to scrape the data from, a table in this URL https://www.mlssoccer.com/stats/players/#season=2023&competition=mls-regular-season&club=all&statType=general&position=all

This is the code that I am using

```py
from selenium import webdriver

url= 'https://www.mlssoccer.com/stats/players/#season=2023&competition=mls-regular-season&club=all&statType=general&position=all'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path-to-chrome>')
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="main-content"]/section').click()
```

And I am, getting this

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58922/devtools/browser/33b52d7e-2f77-4350-8ee8-53dfd9b85314
```

what does that mean ??

Comment: So what's the issue with your code?

Comment: This message is just to show in console log that the chrome driver has started and listening on - `ws://127.0.0.1:58922/devtools/browser/33b52d7e-2f77-4350-8ee8-53dfd9b85314`.

Check for the `XPpath` if `click()` function is not working

Answer (score 0):

This message is just to show in console log that the chrome driver has started and listening on - `ws://127.0.0.1:58922/devtools/browser/33b52d7e-2f77-4350-8ee8-53dfd9b85314`.

Check for the `XPpath` if `click()` function is not working.